# highchart stockchart facing issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have done a line chart and it is working perfectly, except it does not have additional function that a stockchart has.

However I am facing an issue where by,

1) my data does not shows at all but the timing is correct.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>

<script>

var numX = [];
var time = [];
var i = 0;

var url = 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/';
var ws = new WebSocket(url, 'echo-protocol');

ws.onmessage = function(evt) 
{
console.log(evt.data);

var data = evt.data;

data = JSON.parse(data);

var x = data.position_x;

numX[i] = x;
time[i] = data.timestamp;

i++;

    updateChart();

};


function updateChart()
{
$(function () 
{

    Highcharts.setOptions
    ({
        global : 
        {
            useUTC : false
        }
    });

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', 
    {
        chart : 
        {
            events : 
            {
                load : function () 
                {
                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    //setInterval(function () 
                    //{
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = 0;//Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    //}, 1000);
                }
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: 
        {
            buttons: 
            [{
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '1M'
            }, 
            {
                count: 5,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '5M'
            }, 
            {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 0
        },

        title : 
        {
            text : 'Live Coordinate X data'
        },

        exporting: 
        {
            enabled: false
        },

        series : 
        [{
            name : 'Random data',
            data : 

            (function () 
            {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

                for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) 
                {
                    data.push
                    ([
                        time,
                        Math.round(numX)
                    ]);
                }
                return data;
            }())

        }]
    });

});
}


</script>
```

Comment: Also, note that I am using websocket to receive data from my own end. Thus I am able to pump in data.

Comment: How your JSON looks like? Please run the console (developer tools in the Chrome) and let us know if any errors appears?

Comment: thanks, it has been solve.